# How to execute a function at thread end?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, task

with the `AsyncTask` Method in Android, exists the event `onPostExecute()` to execute a code after the end of task. What is the equivalent with the Thread Method? I searched, but I didn't find any solution.

Edit:  I can't place a call at the end of run method because I need to execute operation in the UI thread, and I can't execute this operation in a different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the call at the end of the run method...

```
run(){
    ...
    handler.post(...);
}
```

Comment: No, I can't because I need to execute operation in the UI thread, and i can't execute this operation in a different thread...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your thread inside an Activity you can use the following code inside the thread:

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run(){ //your ui altering code here 
}})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) method to execute code on UI from non UI thread.

If you need more control over the thread events or want to send back progress updates, you should use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [HandlerThread]. Pass the UI handler to the background thread and then post messages using  from the background thread to the UI thread handler. Implement the [handleMessage(message)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#handleMessage(android.os.Message)) to act on those events.